# emv PDOL demands 2 bytes of Terminal capabilities

Tags: emv

i have a funny case which i think i am missing the information somewhere in the specification.

My EMV Card provides this PDOL

```
9F33 02 9F35 01 9F40 01 -> Total length = 4
```

These are my terminal transaction related data

```
Terminal capabilities : 9F33 -> 0xA0 0xA0 0xC0 
Additional Terminal Capabilities  : 9F35 -> 0x16  
Terminal Type                     : 9F40 -> 0x70 0x00 0x80 0xB0 0x01
```

When i get the processing options passing **(A0 A0) bytes 1 and 2** for the 2 bytes of **9F33** **16** for **9F35** and **70** for **9F40** i get a **69 85** status word.

Here is my command (in Hex)

```
80 A8 00 00 06 83 04 A0 A0 16 70 00 -> s1 s2 = 69 85
```

and

When i pass **A0 C0 (Byte 2 and Byte 3)** for **9F33**, i get the success (90 00)

```
80 A8 00 00 06 83 04 A0 C0 16 70 00 -> s1 s2 = 90 00
```

***My Question :***

How do i know exactly what bytes are needed, especially when the required length is less than the actual length?. Where is it documented in the Specification?. I just found this out by intuition.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the rules from Book 3 Chapter 5.4 as you rightly pointed. "c" is the explanation to my results. In my case i had to truncate the right-most bytes (**Byte 2 and 3**) because my Data Object (9F33) does not have a numeric format.

```
a. If the tag of any data object identified in the DOL is unknown to the terminal or represents a constructed data object, the terminal shall provide a data element with the length specified and a value of all hexadecimal zeroes.
b. If a data object is in the list and is meaningful to the terminal but represents optional static data that is absent from the terminal, the portion of the command field representing the data object shall be filled with hexadecimal zeroes.
c. If the length specified in the DOL entry is less than the length of the actual data object, the leftmost bytes of the data element shall be truncated if the data object has numeric (n 1) format, or the rightmost bytes of the data shall be truncated for any other format.
d. If the length specified in the DOL entry is greater than the length of the actual data, the actual data shall be padded:
 with leading hexadecimal zeroes if the data has numeric format
 with trailing hexadecimal 'FF's if the data has compressed numeric (cn 1) format
 with trailing hexadecimal zeroes for any other format (an, ans or b including bit combination data 1)
e. If a data object is in the list and is meaningful to the terminal but represents data that is not applicable to the current transaction, the portion of the command field representing the data object shall be filled with hexadecimal zeroes.
```

Comment: The F in 9F makes it a non-numeric format.' - is incorrect. As per specs( see Annex B1 Coding of the Tag Field of BER-TLV Data Objects) 'F' only means that the subsequent byte is also tag data. To see the format of data a tag holds needs to be checked from Annex A Data Elements Dictionary. Both in Book 3

Comment: Oh you are right. I think i did not understand the definition of "numeric" in Book 3 chapter 4.3. So does it mean that we have to save the dictionary somewhere in a code?. Isn't there a way to decode it from the Tag?. I edited my answer above not to spread wrong infos. Thank you.

Comment: yes, to my understanding you have to take care in your code the type of data it is holding. Good that you also pin pointed the difference based on type of data. btw, do you have an actual reason for difference between A0 A0 and A0 C0 asked in your question ?

Comment: Yes. The actual reason is my Security capability of my Terminal Capability (Book 4 Annex A Table 27). **C0** codes SDA and DDA supported, while **A0** code SDA and Card capture. I can't actually explain why my card did not like **A0** for the security capability.

Answer (score 0):

Any DOLs, when no actual data is available, needs to be zero filled. When the actual length of the data is more than what requested in DOL, then the data should be truncated to the length expected in DOL

For the rules on using the DOL, refer

> EMV 4.3 Book 3
>
> 5.4 Rules for Using a Data Object List (DOL)

btw, did you find the answer to why the GPO response change when the 9F33 value is changed ?

Comment: Sorry i have edited the question above. It was a type error. The values don't correspond to any RFU. But from your suggestion, how would you know the Bytes to provide and the other to set to 0?. Are you also suggesting that i used a total length of 9 instead of 4?. I mean the byte after 0x83.